# How can I solve undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.data') in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm not so experienced in React Native, I'm working on my app and I'm getting this error but I don't know how I can solve it. Please help.

Below is part of my code:

```
  const HomeScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [{ ios, appSettings, rtl_support }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState({ 0: 
  route.params.data });
  const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [bottomLevel, setBottomLevel] = useState(false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing **data parameter to Home screen component** that's why it mentioning it as undefined.

You must use your code in this way in order to ignore errors

```js
 const HomeScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {

 const { data } = route.params; // Here data prop can be undefined if you not pass it to this component as parameter
// navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {data: 'whatever'})

  const [{ ios, appSettings, rtl_support }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState({ 0: data });
  const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [bottomLevel, setBottomLevel] = useState(false);
}
```

> Updated

If this is the first screen then you don't need to use route.

```js
 const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [{ ios, appSettings, rtl_support }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState({ 0: 'whatever here' });
  const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [bottomLevel, setBottomLevel] = useState(false);
}
```

I hope you got it!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242197/discussion-on-answer-by-muhammad-rafeh-atique-how-can-i-solve-undefined-is-not-a).

Comment: @Muhammad Rafeh Atique, hello, are you available to chat on Upwork?

Comment: Yes, I'm available.

Comment: @Amos You can contact me on upwork.

Comment: @Muhammad Rafeh Atique, please check Upwork